# When to use separate SQL databases on the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've worked in several SQL environments.  In one environment, the different tables holding business data were split across several different SQL databases, all on the same server.

In another environment, almost all the tables are kept on one single SQL database.

I'm creating a new project that is closely related to another project, and I've been wondering if I should put the new tables in the same SQL database or a new SQL database.

This all runs on MS SQL Server.

What factors do I need to consider as I make this decision?

Comment: How closely related?  Foreign keys and joins?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm not asking what decision to make here; I'm asking what to consider when making this decision in general.

Comment: To some degree it will still depend on your requirements, and I don't really see any requirements here.

Answer (score 5):

It's tough from your question to tell what your actual requirements are, or what data you would consider to store in different databases. But in addition to Gordon's points I can address a couple of additional reasons why you might want to use separate databases for data belonging to different customers / users (and this answer assumes that one possible separation of data, whether by database or schema, would be by customer):

- As I mentioned in a comment, some customers will *demand* that their data be stored separately, and you may need to agree to that in writing before you see a penny or are able to secure their business. So you may as well be prepared for that inevitability.
- Keeping each customer in their own database makes it very easy to move them if they outgrow your current server. At my previous job we designed the system in this way, and it saved our bacon later - we were able to move customers completely to a different server with what essentially amounted to a metadata operation. During a maintenance window, backed up their database, set the original to offline, restored the backup to a new server, and updated a config table that told all the apps where to find that database. This is much more flexible than trying to extract all of their data from a database shared by others...
- Separate databases also allow you to handle maintenance differently. One customer needs point-in-time restore, and another doesn't? Perfect, you can just use a different recovery model on separate databases. Much easier than separating by filegroups and trying to implement some filegroup-level backup solution, and much more efficient than just treating one big database in full recovery.

This isn't free, of course, it's about trade-offs. Multiple databases scares some people away but having managed such a system for 13 years I can tell you that managing 100 or 500 databases that are largely identical is not that much more complicated than managing 500 schemas in one massive database (in fact I would say it is less so in a lot of respects).

Answer (score 2):

A database is the unit of backup and recovery, so that should be the first consideration when designing database structures.  If the data has different back up and recovery requirements, then they are very good candidates for separate databases.

That is only half the problem, though.  In most environments, backup/recovery is pretty much the same for all databases.  It becomes a question of application design.  In other words, the situation becomes quite subjective.

In the environment that I'm working in right now, here are some criteria for splitting data into different databases:

(1) Publishing tables to a wide audience.  We "publish" data in tables and put these into a database, separate from other tables used for building them or for special purposes.  Admittedly, SQL Server claims that "schema" are the unit of security.  However, databases seem to do a good job in the real world.

(2) Strict security requiremeents.  Some data is so sensitive that lawyers have to approve who can see it.  This goes into its own database, with its own access.

(3) Separation of data tables (which users can see) and tables that describe the production system.

(4) Separation of tables used for general querying by a skilled group of analysts (the published tables) versus tables used for specific reports/applications.

Finally, I would add this.  If some of the data is being updated continuously throughout the day and other data is used for reporting, I would tend to put them in different databases.  This helps separate them in the case of problems.

Comment: To this, I'd add that I've also seen it used for performance to try to spread load across disks by setting the databases to use separate drives. I'd also note that from the technical standpoint, you don't necessarily have to split databases for security. You can do a lot with schemas and roles.

Comment: `It becomes a question of application design. In other words, the situation becomes quite subjective.` That's about what I expected.

Comment: Addressing @JamieSee's comment, you can also put different tables (in different schemas or not) on different filegroups to intelligently spread I/O across different disks without having the logical database separation (using separate databases can make data integrity an issue).

Comment: Good points @Gordon, I'd also add that some customers will demand that their data is stored separately (and often are legally bound to do so). And some just don't want their data to be mixed with that of others, lawyers or not.